# How do I fix this environment setup?

Tags: enumerate

I have the following MWE with the environment "myenum" to changes the spacing. However, the items are not enumerated, they all have "0.". Is it possible to start enumerating them at 1?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myenum}[2]{\begin{list}{\labelenumi}{\setlength{\itemsep}{#1}\setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenum}{-0.5em}{0em}

\item xxx
\item yyy

\end{myenum}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) I think it is a waste of time doing it like this, see the `enumitem` package. Much better interface and easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

How about use one of the packages developed just for such issues (`enumitem`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-0.5em,labelwidth=0em]
\item xxx
\item yyy
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed to initalise the counter for your list definition, here, I've inserted the tag "`\usecounter{enumi}`" in your definition, see the updated code below:

```
\newenvironment{myenum}[2]{\begin{list}{\labelenumi}{\usecounter{enumi}\setlength{\itemsep}{#1}\setlength{\labelwidth}{#2}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}}}{\end{list}}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? Posting just code which is not even a MWE without explanation may not be very helpful to others (especially beginners).